# Question about sum and list in a function

Tags: function-construction, summation

I have a list of this form:

$ lst =\left\{\left\{q_1,x_1,y_1,z_1\right\},\left\{q_2,x_2,y_2,z_2\right\},\text{...},\left\{q_n,x_n,y_n,z_n\right\}\right\} $

I want to use this list in the function:

$V(\{x,y,z\})=\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{q_i}{\sqrt{\left(x_i-x\right){}^2+\left(y_i-y\right){}^2+\left(z_i-z\right){}^2}}$

Where n is the lenght of the list n = Length[lst]. I am not sure how i get this into a inpute code. I have tried the following with the list lst and function v2 :

```
lst= {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

$ \text{V2}(\{\text{x$\_$},\text{y$\_$},\text{z$\_$}\},\text{lst$\_$})\text{:=}\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{\text{lst}[[\text{All},1]]}{\sqrt{\left(\text{lst}[[\text{All},2]]_i-x\right){}^2+\left(\text{lst}[[\text{All},3]]_i-y\right){}^2+\left(\text{lst}[[\text{All},4]]_i-z\right){}^2}}$

```
    V2[{x_, y_, z_}, lst_] := 
       Sum[lst[[All,1]]/Sqrt[(Subscript[lst[[All,2]], i] - x)^2 + (Subscript[lst[[All,3]], i] - y)^2 + 
           (Subscript[lst[[All,4]], i]- z)^2], {i, 1, n}];
```

---

```
    Apply[V2, {{x, y, z}, lst}]
```

Gives :
$ \left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_2-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_2-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_2-z\right){}^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_3-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_3-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_3-z\right){}^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_1-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_1-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_1-z\right){}^2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_2-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_2-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_2-z\right){}^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_3-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_3-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_3-z\right){}^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_1-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_1-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_1-z\right){}^2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_2-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_2-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_2-z\right){}^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_3-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_3-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_3-z\right){}^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\{0,-1,1\}_1-x\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_1-y\right){}^2+\left(\{0,0,0\}_1-z\right){}^2}}\right\}$

But i am expecting to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2+z^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2}} $

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use $\LaTeX$ for _Mathematica_ code... edit your question to convert the code to something that's copy-pastable (use `InputForm`).

Comment: @rm-rf I already left such a comment and I believe the OP has put all the necessary input in code (as well as TeX).  Makes the formatting look a little messy I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method

```
#/Sqrt[(#2 - x)^2 + (#3 - y)^2 + (#4 - z)^2] & @@@ lst // Total
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, "what am I doing wrong", I'd say that you are using the wrong syntax to access elements in a list. It's easier to start from scratch than to correct your code.
(Edited to explain when it is better to use delayed rule assignment)

This, for example, will do what you want

```
Plus @@ (lst /. {qn_, xn_, yn_, zn_} -> qn/Sqrt[(xn - x)^2 + (yn - y)^2 + (zn - z)^2])
```

What I have done here is to use a replacement rule to turn each list `{qk,xk,yk,zk}` contained in `lst` into the corresponding contribute to the field. Then I sum all the contributes by changing the head of `lst` from `List` to `Plus`.

You can enclose the above code in a procedure that accepts the `{x,y,z}` vector and the list `lst`, if you wish:

```
v2[{x_, y_, z_}, lst_] := Plus @@ (lst /. 
    {qn_, xn_, yn_, zn_} -> qn/Sqrt[(xn - x)^2 + (yn - y)^2 + (zn - z)^2]
)
```

But if you choose to code the rule in a separate portion of code and then applying it manually, you'd be better off with a delayed rule assignment like this:

```
toFieldContribute = {qn_, xn_, yn_, zn_} :> qn/Sqrt[(xn - x)^2 + (yn - y)^2 + (zn - z)^2]
```

in this way, even if you had values associated with x,y or z (it is not uncommon, given the names), they would not show up in the definition of the above rule, because the evaluation will take place only when the rule is applied, like in

```
Total[ lst /. toFieldContribute ]
```

In this way only the actual values of x, y or z would be used. try *with a fresh kernel* by evaluating x=2, then the rule definition, then x=5 and then apply it as above. You will get different results with `->` and `:>`

To show yet another approach, and to make the answer more similar to your tentative solution, you could do code your procedure in this way

```
v2[{x_, y_, z_}, lst_] := Block[n = Length[lst], 
    Sum[lst[[k, 1]]/Sqrt[
        (lst[[k, 2]] - x)^2 + (lst[[k, 3]] - y)^2 + (lst[[k, 4]] - z)^2],
    {k, 1, n}
    ]
]
```

(here I have used `Block` to limit the scope of `n`, and I used the index `k` to refer to the `k`-th element of `lst`, while 1,2,3 and 4 refer to the elements in each sublist `{qk,xk,yk,zk}`).
But I believe my former approach to be faster (and somewhat tidier).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and explanation. I had one question, why do you need to use a RuleDelayed in your first method?

Comment: In this case, since the rule is defined and applied in the same line, there strictly is no reason to do that. But I usually like to write my code in pieces and if you define `toFieldRule={qn_, xn_, yn_, zn_} -> qn/Sqrt[(xn - x)^2 + (yn - y)^2 + (zn - z)^2])` you might end up with a rule definition tainted by values previously assigned to x, y or z so that when you apply it later in `lst/.toFieldRule` you will get results with those values and not the actual values of x,y and z.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward way. First, break apart the list into the `xyz` parts and the `q` parts. The denominators are just the `Norm` which are summed uing `Total`.

```
list = {{q1, x1, y1, z1}, {q2, x2, y2, z2}, {q3, x3, y3, z3}, {q4, x4, y4, z4}}; 
xyz = list[[All, 2 ;; 4]];
q = list[[All, 1]];
Sum[q[[i]]/Norm[xyz[[i]]], {i, Length[list]}]

q1/Sqrt[Abs[x1]^2 + Abs[y1]^2 + Abs[z1]^2] + q2/Sqrt[Abs[x2]^2 + Abs[y2]^2 + Abs[z2]^2] 
  + q3/Sqrt[Abs[x3]^2 + Abs[y3]^2 + Abs[z3]^2] + q4/Sqrt[Abs[x4]^2 + Abs[y4]^2 + Abs[z4]^2]
```

which is the desired sum.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
v[x_, y_, z_, list_] := 
 Total[#1/Sqrt[({##2} - {x, y, z}).({##2} - {x, y, z})] & @@@ list]
```

Applying to

```
lst = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}};
v[x, y, z, lst]
```

yields:

1/Sqrt[(-1 - x)^2 + y^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[(1 - x)^2 + y^2 + 
  z^2] + 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]

If you don't mind the `Abs` then this could be done more compactly:

```
v2[x_, y_, z_, list_] := Total[#1/Norm[{##2} - {x, y, z}] & @@@ list]
```